# How do I display the first 40 rows from one sheet into another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Simple Question

How do I display the content of the first 40 rows from one sheet into another sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do that.

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Z40)
```

OR

```
=ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet1'!A1:Z40)
```

OR

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!A1:Z40)
```

OR

```
=IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxxxx","'Sheet1'!A1:Z40")
```

*(`IMPORTRANGE` can also be used to import data to a different spreadsheet where `xxxxxxxx` is the ID of the source spreadsheet)*

Functions used:

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)